# Style label when input inside of it is checked

Tags: html, css, input, label, checked

I'm losing my mind how to make this work. I have HTML code below. I want to apply style on label and when input is checked I want to style label background. Is there any solution for this, because I can not make it work with input:checked+label, label+input:checked.... Nothing works.

```
<ul class="wcsatt-options-prompt-radios">
<li class="wcsatt-options-prompt-radio">
    <label type="radio" class="wcsatt-options-prompt-label wcsatt-options-prompt-label-one-time">
        <input class="wcsatt-options-prompt-action-input" type="radio" name="subscribe-to-action-input" value="no" />
        <span class="wcsatt-options-prompt-action"><?php echo $one_time_cta; ?></span> 
        <span class="subs-box-price">Price</span>
        <div class="sub-sub-text">Save 20$</div>        
    </label>
</li>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED:

I added this alternative solution using JQuery, since your label is the parent of the input and there's currently no way of selecting a child's parent using the [CSS Combinators](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp):

```js
$('#radio-label').click(function() {
   if($('#input-radio').is(':checked')) { 
   $('#radio-label').toggleClass('has-background-color'); }
});
```

```css
.has-background-color {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="wcsatt-options-prompt-radios">
<li class="wcsatt-options-prompt-radio">
    <label id="radio-label" type="radio" for="input-radio" class="wcsatt-options-prompt-label wcsatt-options-prompt-label-one-time">
        <input id="input-radio" class="wcsatt-options-prompt-action-input" type="radio" name="subscribe-to-action-input" value="no" />
        <span class="wcsatt-options-prompt-action"><?php echo $one_time_cta; ?></span> 
        <span id="subs-box-price-text" class="subs-box-price">Price</span>
        <div class="sub-sub-text">Save 20$</div>        
    </label>
</li>
```

**Original Post:**

Instead of using "+", you should use the "~" combinator.

Use the "for" attribute (in the label element) and "id" attribute (in the input element) to connect your label to your input.

Then, use the tilde "~" in your CSS selector as below, which is known as the "Subsequent-sibling combinator" since your input element and your span element share the same parent.

Quoted from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-does-symbol-tilde-denotes-in-css/

The fact that you use "+" can't work because it is used to select the next immediate sibling element.

You can take a look about CSS Combinators for more details:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

In the code I only change the background color of the span tag for price. You can modify the code as you wish.

```css
#input-radio:checked~#subs-box-price-text {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wcsatt-options-prompt-radios">
<li class="wcsatt-options-prompt-radio">
    <label type="radio" for="input-radio" class="wcsatt-options-prompt-label wcsatt-options-prompt-label-one-time">
        <input id="input-radio" class="wcsatt-options-prompt-action-input" type="radio" name="subscribe-to-action-input" value="no" />
        <span class="wcsatt-options-prompt-action"><?php echo $one_time_cta; ?></span> 
        <span id="subs-box-price-text" class="subs-box-price">Price</span>
        <div class="sub-sub-text">Save 20$</div>        
    </label>
</li>
```

Comment: Hm, but I want to style background of label element. Tried your solution but doesn't work for label?

Comment: I added an alternative solution using JQuery. I agree with @Bill Criswell that you can't style a parent based on a state of a child.

Comment: Amazing hiew1, thank you so much, works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can't style based on the state of a child. With the selector you're using (a sibling selector) it looks like you want the label to be a sibling of the radio button.

```
<input type="radio">
<label>Hi</label>
```

Then you can do `:checked + label { background-color: red }`.

In the comments you asked about how to keep the markup and do this with jQuery. You can do something like:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(event) {
  const $input = $(this)
  $input.closest('label').toggleClass('checked', $input.checked)
})
```

Comment: I need to keep input inside label. So there is no way to style it? Or is it somehow possible with jQuery?

Comment: Added a quick edit. Beena. while since I touched jQuery but should work.